# How to disable HTML button on the click using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Once my button gets clicked, it should get disabled and never be clicked again until the page is refreshed. Below is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myButtonClicked()
{
    alert("Has myButton got disabled? I need solution for this.");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" id="myButton1" onclick="myButtonClicked()">Click ME</button>
<button type="button" id="myButton2" onclick="myButtonClicked()">Click ME</button>
<button type="button" id="myButton3" onclick="myButtonClicked()">Click ME</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Before calling myButtonClicked function, it should get disabled. Actually, I want to write a PHP script in this function which will fetch some data from database which will take some time in real environment. That is why I want to disable the button. How do I achieve that?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/falevumo/1/edit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass `this` to your function:

```
<button type="button" id="myButton1" onclick="myButtonClicked(this)">Click ME</button>
<button type="button" id="myButton2" onclick="myButtonClicked(this)">Click ME</button>
<button type="button" id="myButton3" onclick="myButtonClicked(this)">Click ME</button>
```

then you can use:

```
function myButtonClicked(el)
{
    el.disabled = true; 
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X99Um/)**

with jQuery you can use **[.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)** along with **[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)**:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).prop('disabled',true);
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AzTGW/)**

Comment: Yup, gotta mention jQuery 'cause it solves every problem in the whole universe :P

Comment: @Felix - If I write alert("hello"); after el.disabled = true; in your fiddle, alert is not fired, although button is disabled.

Comment: @Felix - yes, it worked, sorry it was my mistake :). Thanks for the simple solution for my problem. Accepting your answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
function myButtonClicked()
{
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
}
```

Is it helping?

Comment: do you have jQuery included?

Comment: if its old version .prop may not work. try with .attr("disabled", true);

Answer (score 1):

Add -

```
function myButtonClicked()
{
    alert("Has myButton got disabled? I need solution for this.");
    this.disabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your element as an argument within calling teh function

```
   <button type="button" id="myButton1" onclick="myButtonClicked(this)">Click ME</button>
   <button type="button" id="myButton2" onclick="myButtonClicked(this)">Click ME</button>
   <button type="button" id="myButton3" onclick="myButtonClicked(this)">Click ME</button>
```

And set the element attribute "disabled" to true

```
function myButtonClicked(obj) {
        obj.setAttribute("disabled", true);
    }
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/quJX8/

Answer (score 1):

**[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/falevumo/1/edit)**

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $('#'+this.id).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable like this, this is self explainable:

```
<script>
function myButtonClicked(id)
{
    alert("Has myButton got disabled? I need solution for this.");

    $("#" + id).attr("disabled", true);
}
</script>

<body>
<button type="button" id="myButton1" onclick="myButtonClicked(this.id)">Click ME</button>
<button type="button" id="myButton2" onclick="myButtonClicked(this.id)">Click ME</button>
<button type="button" id="myButton3" onclick="myButtonClicked(this.id)">Click ME</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are simpler ways than rewriting your function and passing "this".  Just use "this" in your onclick attribute:

```
<button type="button" id="myButton1" onclick="this.disabled=true;myButtonClicked()">Click ME</button>
```

That will disable it, but it isn't necessarily that visibly obvious on the form.  I like to use:

```
<button type="button" id="myButton1" onclick="this.style.visibility='hidden';myButtonClicked()">Click ME</button>
```

Which "disappears" it, but it still holds its place in the form.

If you don't need the placeholder, you can also use:

```
<button type="button" id="myButton1" onclick="this.hidden=true;myButtonClicked()">Click ME</button>
```